# Scale raster cell in stack from -1 to 1 R

Tags: r, scale, raster

I have a raster stack with 364 layers with a daily rate of change in NDVI values.

I want to scale these values in every cell if positive from 0 to 1 and if negative from -1 to 0. So far I have only found a solution that scale values in single layers (see here: [Replace specific value in each band of raster brick in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266752/replace-specific-value-in-each-band-of-raster-brick-in-r)) and not along cells of multilayer objects. Additionally I have a decent amount of cells with NA for the entire time series and I'm not quite sure how to deal with this fact either.

I took the code from the previously mentioned post and tried to get it working for my problem:

```
norm <- function(x){-1+(x-min)*((1-(-1))/(max-min))}

for(j in 1:ncell(tif)){

 if(is.na(sum(tif[j]))){
  NULL
 } else {

 cat(paste("Currently processing layer:", j,"/",ncell(tif), "\n"))

 min <- cellStats(tif[j],'min')
 max <- cellStats(tif[j],'max')

#initialize cluster
#number of cores to use for clusterR function (max recommended: ncores - 1)
beginCluster(31)

#normalize
tif[j] <- clusterR(tif[j], calc, args=list(fun=norm), export=c('min',"max"))

#end cluster
endCluster()
}
}
```

I'm not quite certain if this produces the desired output. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
s <- stack(lapply(1:5, function(i) setValues(r, runif(100, -1, 1))))
# adding NAs
s[[2]][sample(100, 25, TRUE)] <- NA
```

For scaling (or any other operation) *by cell* (as requested) you can use `calc` together with a function that works on a vector. For example:

```
ff <- function(i) {
    p <- which(i >= 0)
    n <- which(i <= 0)
    # positive values
    if (length(p) > 0) {
        i[p] <- i[p] - min(i[p], na.rm=TRUE)
        i[p] <- i[p] / max(i[p])
    }
    # negative values
    if (length(n) > 0) {
        i[n] <- i[n] - max(i[n], na.rm=TRUE)
        i[n] <- i[n] / abs(min(i[n]))
    }
    i
}
```

Test it

```
ff(c(-.3, -.1, .1, .4, .8))
#[1] -1.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.4285714  1.0000000
ff(c(-.3, -.1, .1, .4, .8, NA))
#[1] -1.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.4285714  1.0000000         NA
ff(c(-2,-1))
#[1] -1  0
ff(c(NA, NA))
#[1] NA NA
```

And use it

```
z <- calc(s, ff)
```

See the below to scale *by layer*, based on the min and max of all cell values (I first thought that this is what was asked for). Note that the functions I used below scale values from -1 to 1, but not the lowest positive value and highest negative value to zero.

```
minv <- abs(cellStats(s,'min'))
maxv <- cellStats(s,'max')

f1 <- function(i, mn, mx) {
    j <- i < 0
    j[is.na(j)] <- TRUE
    i[j] <- i[j] / abs(mn)
    i[!j] <- i[!j] / mx
    i
}

ss <- list()
for (i in 1:nlayers(s)) {
    ss[[i]] <- calc(s[[i]], fun=function(x) f1(x, minv[i], maxv[i]))
}

ss1 <- stack(ss)
```

Or without a loop

```
f2 <- function(x, mn, mx) {
    x <- t(x)
    i <- which(x > 0)
    i[is.na(i)] <- FALSE
    mxx <- x / mx
    x <- x / mn
    x[i] <- mxx[i]
    t(x)
}

ss2 <- calc(s, fun=function(x) f2(x, minv, maxv))
```

For reference, to simply scale between 0 and 1

```
mnv <- cellStats(s,'min')
mxv <- cellStats(s,'max')
x <- (s - mnv) / (mxv - mnv)
```

To get values between -1 and 1 you can then do

```
y <- 2 * (x - 1)
```

But that way previously negative values can become positive and vice versa.

See `?raster::scale` for other types of scaling.

Comment: thanks for this great answer! It is almost what I need, but as far as I understood it, this solution works with the min/max values per layer and I would need one that works with the min/max per cell (kind of a local min/max) in order to scale every cell from -1 to 1, don't I?

Comment: OK, I missed that because you used cellStats in your code.