# How to make multiple RasterLayers in R have the same scale?

Tags: r, raster, normalization

I am looking for a way to convert the scale of multiple rasters to the same scale.

I currently have three different rasters that are `Large RasterLayer` in `R` and were created from a landcover database. The `Large RasterLayers` (shown here) were created by multiplying each individual raster cells with a coefficient from a selection model from a model I ran. My issue is that these rasters are not directly comparable because the scale within each raster is different. I am trying to find a way to convert the scale in each raster to the same scale (say convert each raster where the scale is 0-1); however, I am unable to figure out this issue.

Any suggestions?
[image: Raster with landcover] [image: Raster with landcover] [image: Raster with landcover]

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example. That is, create three small RasterLayers with code. See the documentation for almost any raster method for examples. There is no need for plots, but rather `show(x)` your data.

Comment: Does the answer to this thread help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52269607/scale-raster-cell-in-stack-from-1-to-1-r

Answer (score 0):

To scale some numbers, for example

```
x <- c(-2,4,6.6)
```

to a range between 0 and 1, you can do

```
y = (x - min(x, na.rm=TRUE))
y = y / max(y, na.rm=TRUE)
y
#[1] 0.0000000 0.6976744 1.0000000
```

Comment: So this could be used on each raster to scale them between 0 and 1?

Comment: Why ask? Just try it.